# To see javascript object properties and functions with intellisense in VS.NET 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

I am creating classes in external files.And adding them with `<script src='../js/clsClassName.js' type='text/javascript'></script>` tags. When i created an object from this class I can't access its props, and functions with intellisense.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Sample javascript class:

```
// clsClassName.js
function ClassName(_param1, _param2, _param3) {

    this.Prop1 = _param1;
    this.Prop1 = _param2;
    this.Prop3 = _param3;
}



ClassName.prototype.f_Add = function(fBefore, fSuccess, fComplete, fError) {
}


ClassName.prototype.f_Delete = function(fBefore, fSuccess, fComplete, fError) {
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I personally never get this to show up; you can manually enter the props and it will work fine.